How to prevent a Linux shell from intercepting escape sequence so it can be sent over serial TTY
I am working on an embedded system that is connected over USB serial TTY (i.e. /dev/ttyUSB0), which needs to interpret arrow keys sent via a virtual terminal such as screen. The problem is, the shell (bash) and or screen seems to digest the escape sequence and then send on just the last byte. So, taking the up-arrow key for example - \033[A (or ESC followed by [A), my embedded system on the other end of the serial terminal only receives A. Interestingly, or perhaps expectedly, a terminal emulator like TeraTerm under Windows has no issue passing on arrow keys to the same USB-connected hardware.
The behavior makes sense, I think; the terminal/shell needs to read the control characters, but is there any way to pass the sequences on untouched through serial without some kind of keyboard gymnastics or special program? I'd like to be able to do this on any system without any special extra software and using basic utilities.

Just to exclude one factor, is the problem still there if screen is not involved?

@Alexander yes the problem is still there using echo/cat from bash - echo -ne '\033[A' > /dev/ttyUSB0 also produces A response using cat -v < /dev/ttyUSB0

That sounds like you're only looking at what's echoed back and not actually looking at what's sent?

@u1686_grawity Yes, that sounds right - well spotted ... the shell is consuming the ESC and the following character and deciding, according to the terminal type, it is an invalid ESC sequence and doing nothing with it (except discarding it). @Antennae What is your terminal type set to in bash on the embedded system? e.g. echo "$TERM" ... embedded systems sometimes have a limited set of terminal types installed - look in /usr/share/terminfo to see which types are available.

...and is it truly bash, and not (e.g.) dash or busybox-ash?

@u1686_grawity the embedded system will simply echo back any normal characters received (hence echoing back simply A). I can also debug the microcontroller in real time and see that it is indeed only receiving a single A character on the UART - the Linux host never sent the ESC. My Linux host is indeed using bash, the embedded system is not Linux - it is a custom command-line interface running within FreeRTOS.

OK, I think I get it now ... you are using screen to connect to the serial device (I didn't know screen could do that, I thought it was just a multiplexor. Personally, I wouldn't use it for this purpose, I'd use minicom etc, in a screen virtual terminal - but maybe that is inefficient ... actually I wouldn't use screen at all, I'd just use minicom in a terminal window). Anyway, screen only supports VT100 or ANSI/ISO sequences - see section 11 of the screen manual - in particular, section 11.2, which explains how to map keys.

It just occurred to me that you might have the terminal type in the window on the Linux host set incorrectly ... the value of the TERM environment variable must match the terminal type that the window is emulating - if these do match, then I think screen should set up the input translation correctly (via termcap) to map arrow keys to the VT100 or ANSI/ISO equivalent, if I am reading the manual correctly. Your embedded system will need to support VT100 or ANSI/ISO terminal type. To find out what the terminal type is set to, run echo "$TERM" just before running the screen command.

In screen, force ESC pass thru with:

Ctrl-a :flow off
Ctrl-a :send-esc


Thanks for the suggestion, but :send-esc produces and "unknown command" error. I've googled extensively for the "ESC pass thru" you mentioned but have not found a solution. FYI other terminal emulators (minicom, picocom, tio, etc) produce the same behavior.
